# Kubernetes Pod-to-Pod Communication Cross Nodes

Tags: linux-networking, kubernetes

## Troubleshooting Pod-to-Pod Communication Cross Nodes

#### **Prerequisite:**

I use VirtualBox to setup 2 VMs. VirtualBox version is `6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)`.  The OS is CentOS-7(`CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-2003.iso`).
One VM as kubernetes master node, named `k8s-master1`. Another VM as kubernetes worker node, named `k8s-node1`.
Attach 2 network interfaces, NAT + Host-Only. NAT is used for internet facing. Host-Only is used for connections among VMs.

The network information on `k8s-master1`.

```
[root@k8s-master1 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d1:41:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::62ae:c676:da76:cbff/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8a:2d:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.15/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 80380sec preferred_lft 80380sec
    inet6 fe80::952e:9af8:a1cb:8a07/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:04:6e:c7:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:cd:b1:24:62:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.0.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4cd:b1ff:fe24:62fc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: cni0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:75:06:d0:17:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.0.1/24 brd 10.244.0.255 scope global cni0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::475:6ff:fed0:17ee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth221fb276@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 62:b9:61:95:0f:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::60b9:61ff:fe95:f73/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The network information on `k8s-node1`.

```
[root@k8s-node1 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ba:34:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.102/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::660d:ec2:cb1c:49de/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:48:6d:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.15/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 80039sec preferred_lft 80039sec
    inet6 fe80::62af:7770:3b6d:6576/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e4:65:f4:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 8e:d3:79:63:40:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.1.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8cd3:79ff:fe63:4022/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: cni0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:22:8d:e5:29:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.1.1/24 brd 10.244.1.255 scope global cni0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8c22:8dff:fee5:2924/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth5314dbaf@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 82:58:1c:3a:a1:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::8058:1cff:fe3a:a1a3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: calic849a8cefe4@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: cali82f9786c604@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: caliaa01fae8214@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: cali88097e17cd0@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: cali788346fba46@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: caliafdfba3871a@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: cali329803e4ee5@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I make a table to simplify the network information.

```
| k8s-master1                               | k8s-node1                                  |
| ----------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------ |
| NAT               10.0.3.15/24    enp0s8  | NAT                10.0.3.15/24    enp0s8  |
| Host-Only     192.168.56.101/24    enp0s3 | Host-Only      192.168.56.102/24    enp0s3 |
| docker0        172.17.0.1/16              | docker0         172.17.0.1/16              |
| flannel.1       10.244.1.0/32             | flannel.1        10.244.1.0/32             |
| cni0               10.244.1.1/24          | cni0                10.244.1.1/24          |
```

#### **Problem Description**

**Test case1:**

Expose Kubernetes Service `nginx-svc` as NodePort, and Pod `nginx` is running on `k8s-node1`。

*View the NodePort of nginx-svc*

```
[root@k8s-master1 ~]# kubectl get svc 
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-svc               NodePort    10.103.236.60    <none>        80:30309/TCP   9h
```

Run command `curl http://localhost:30309` on `k8s-master1`. Finally, it returns `Connection timed out`.

[image]

Run command `curl http://localhost:30309` on `k8s-node1`. It returns response.

[image]

**Test case 2**:

I created another Pod nginx on `k8s-master1`. There is already  a Pod nginx on `k8s-node1`. Make a call from the Pod nginx on `k8s-master1` to the Pod nginx on `k8s-node1`. It also `Connection timed out`. The problem is very likely to [could not communicate cross node's pod in kubernetes cluster using flannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171023/could-not-communicate-cross-nodes-pod-in-kubernetes-cluster-using-flannel)

**Test case 3**:

If 2 nginx pod on the same node, whatever `k8s-master1` or `k8s-node1`. The connection is ok. The pod can get response from another pod.

**Test case 4:**

I did several `ping` requests from `k8s-master1` to `k8s-node1` using different IP address.

Ping `k8s-node1`'s Host-Only IP address:          **Connection Success**

```
ping 192.168.56.102
```

Ping `k8s-node1`'s flannel.1 IP address:             **Connection Failed**

```
ping 10.244.1.0
```

Ping `k8s-node1`'s cni0 IP address:                      **Connection Failed**

```
ping 10.244.1.1
```

**Test case 5:**

I setup a new k8s cluster using bridge network on the same laptop. Test case 1,2,3,4 cannot be reproduced. No problem of 'Pod-to-Pod Communication Cross Nodes'.

#### **Guess**

1. Firewall. I disabled the firewall on all VMs. Also the firewall on laptop(Win 10), including any antivirus software. The connection problem is still there.
2. Compare the iptables between k8s cluster attached NAT & Host-Only with k8s cluster attached bridge network. Not found any big difference.

   ```
   yum install -y net-tools
   iptables -L
   ```

#### **Solution**

```
# install route
[root@k8s-master1 tzhong]# yum install -y net-tools

# View routing table after k8s cluster installed thru. kubeadm.
[root@k8s-master1 tzhong]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
10.244.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
10.244.1.0      10.244.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp0s8
```

Focus on the below routing table rule. This rule means that all the requests from `k8s-master1`, and the destination is `10.244.1.0/24` will be forwarded by `flannel.1`.

But seems that the `flannel.1` has some problems. So I just have a try. Add a new routing table rule that all the requests from `k8s-master1`, and the destination is `10.244.1.0/24` will be forwarded by `enp0s8`.

```
# Run below commands on k8s-master1 to add routing table rules. 10.244.1.0 is the IP address of flannel.1 on k8s-node1.
route add -net 10.244.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 enp0s8
route add -net 10.244.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.244.1.0

[root@k8s-master1 ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
10.244.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
10.244.1.0      10.244.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s8
10.244.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
10.244.1.0      10.244.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp0s8
```

Two additional routing table rules has been added.

```
10.244.1.0      10.244.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s8
10.244.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

Do the same way on `k8s-node1`.

```
# Run below commands on k8s-node1 to add routing table rules. 10.244.0.0 is the IP address of flannel.1 on k8s-master1.
route add -net 10.244.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 enp0s8
route add -net 10.244.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.244.0.0
```

**Do test case 1,2,3,4,5 again. All passed.** I am confused, why? I have a couple of questions.

#### Questions:

1. Why the connection of `flannel.1` is blocked? Any way/methods to investigation?
2. Is that a limitation of Host-Only network interface with flannel? If I change to other CNI plugins, the connection will be ok?
3. After add routing tables using `enp0s8`, why the connection becomes ok?

Comment: Looks like CNI-specific problem. Did you try different CNI e.g. Calico ?

Comment: No. I am going to have a try with Calico.

Comment: Hi, any progress with solving this issue ? Was the try with Calico successfull ?

Comment: Sorry. Busy with other things. I will give feedback when I do a try,

Comment: Finally, I found the root cause. I use VirtualBox to setup the VM, there is 2 network interface. One is NAT for the internet-facing, and another is Host-Only for k8s cluster communication. Flannel always uses the NAT. This is not correct. We need to config the correct network interface vaule in kube-flannel.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the root cause. I use VirtualBox to setup the VM, there is 2 network interface. One is NAT for the internet-facing, and another is Host-Only for k8s cluster communication. Flannel always uses the NAT. This is not correct. We need to config the correct network interface vaule in kube-flannel.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.13.1-rc1
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        # THIS LINE
        - --iface=enp0s8
```